# Prove that: $ \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \frac{\tan \frac{\theta}{2^i}}{2^i}= \frac{1}{\theta} - 2 \cot 2 \theta$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

#### My attempt:

Consider the following series:

$$ S = \sum_{i=0}^n \ln( \sec \frac{x}{2^i} )$$

Notice that $ \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{dS}{dx}$ is the required sum.

Simplfying S,

$$ S = - \ln \left(  \cos x \cdot \cos \frac{x}{2} ... \cos \frac{x}{2^n} \right)$$

or,

$$ S = - \ln \left(  \frac{ \sin(2x)}{2^{n+1} \sin (\frac{x}{2^n})} \right)= \ln(2^{n+1}) + \ln( \sin \frac{x}{2^n}) - \ln( \sin(2x) )$$

Now,

$$ \frac{dS}{dx}  = \frac{1}{2^n} \cot \frac{x}{2^n} - 2 \cot(2x)$$

The problem I'm having is proving that

$$ \lim_{ n \to \infty} \frac{1}{2^n} \cot \frac{x}{2^n} = \frac{1}{x}$$

Comment: Hint: $$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{w \to 0} w\cot w = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{w \to 0} \frac{w}{{\sin w}}\mathop {\lim }\limits_{w \to 0} \cos w =  \cdots 
$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a calculus-free solution, prove by induction $\sum_{i=0}^n2^{-i}\tan\tfrac{\theta}{2^i}=2^{-n}\cot(2^{-n}\theta)-2\cot2\theta$ for $n\ge0$. Since $\tan x=\cot x-2\cot2x$, the left-hand side is a telescoping series.

Comment: hmm how did you get that identity? $ \tan x = \cot x - 2 \cot 2 x$

Comment: @Buraian The proof is famous: let $t:=\tan x$ so $\cot x=\tfrac1t,\,\cot2x=\tfrac{1-t^2}{2t}$.

Comment: Oh.  That is a nice idea

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @gary,

$ \frac{1}{2^n} = u$,

$$ \lim_{u \to 0 } u \cot ( ux)=  \lim_{u \to 0} \cos(ux) \frac{ux}{x\sin (ux)} = \frac{1}{x}$$